# Using variable for filter term key in elasticsearch-dsl-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

When using elasticsearch-dsl python api ,is there any way to pass a variable as key in filter .
Please have a look in the code below.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

es_client = Elasticsearch(['http://10.220.3.40'], port='9200')
param1 = 'xyz'
s = Search(using=es_client, index="index1", doc_type="sampledoc").filter("term", Key=param1)

print("Query 1 :"+str(s.to_dict()))
key_varialble_name = 'Key2'
s = Search(using=es_client, index="index1", doc_type="sampledoc").filter("term", key_varialble_name=param1)
print("Query 2 :"+str(s.to_dict()))
```

Here ,the variable named **'key_varialble_name'** has a value assigned as **'Key2'**.

But when used inside the filter,that value is not getting replaced and as a result the term key is containing the variable name (i.e. **'key_varialble_name'** ) instead of the variable value (i.e. **'Key2'** ).

I do not have much knowledge on python.

Can anybody let me know if there is anyway to pass the variable value as key here ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel suggested ,use pass a dictionary object here to pass the key value pair and it would work .Your changed code would like the following .

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

es_client = Elasticsearch(['http://10.220.3.40'], port='9200')
param1 = 'xyz'
s = Search(using=es_client, index="index1", doc_type="sampledoc").filter("term", Key=param1)

print("Query 1 :"+str(s.to_dict()))
dictionary_variable = {"Key2":param1}

s = Search(using=es_client, index="index1", doc_type="sampledoc").filter("term", ** dictionary_variable)
print("Query 2 :"+str(s.to_dict()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `**` with a dictionary for this.

```
....filter("term", **{key_variable_name: param1})
```